# Android Actionbar Tabs like Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, tabs, android-actionbar

im developing an Android App, and i want a tab navigation like the Facebook app.

im using the native actionbar with this code:

```
        final ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.warnung).setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.warnung).setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.warnung).setTabListener(this));

        @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(tab.getPosition()){
        case 0:
            Fragment fragment = new Nachrichten_fragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).commit();
            break;
        }

    }
```

my problem is that unlike in the facebook app, android creats a tab bar below the action bar and not inside it.

so can anyone tell me how to create such a navigation ? or do i need the actionbar sherlock ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom view inside the `ActionBar`. You can use
`getSupportActionBar().setCustomView()`

This way you can both put the tabs in `ActionBar` and make them appear at the middle of the `ActionBar`.

Or you can disable app title and logo using the below functions and you will get the tabs at the top automatically.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```